# How can I view github tasks which are not assigned to a person?

Tags: github

On the main Issues page, you can click `Everyone's Issues`, or `Assigned to me`.

If you want to view the tasks assigned to a particular person, you can click the `search` icon, and on the left choose the `assigned to anyone` drop-down, then choose from a list of assignees.

But how to I list all the items which are not assigned to anyone?

Answer (score 3):

Use the API: http://developer.github.com/v3/issues/

For example, to get all issues on kripken/emscripten with no assignee:

```
curl "https://api.github.com/repos/kripken/emscripten/issues?assignee=none"
```

Comment: as of `now` you could do `no:assignee` on the filters